# How can I trigger an HTTP Cloud Function from within Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-iam

I have a Flask app in Google App Engine Standard Environment Python, and I also have a Cloud Function with an HTTP trigger which accepts a JSON body including the URL of a file.  The CF downloads the file at that URL then saves it to a GCS bucket.  The GAE service account has Cloud Function Invoker permissions, yet when using `urlfetch.fetch()` in my GAE code to trigger CF, the App Engine code gets a `403 Forbidden` error unless I make the CF trigger callable by anyone.

How do I successfully call/trigger CF's from GAE in Python?   I assume the answer is one of these:

1. Set IAM permissions on GAE service account to {enlighten me here}
2. Add authentication headers in `urlfetch.fetch()` like so {different enlightenment}
3. Make CF triggerable from anywhere, but hard code some secret key so the CF code itself handles authentication.

Comment: You need to add an HTTP `Authorization: Bearer [IDENTITY_TOKEN]` header when calling Cloud Functions protected by IAP authorization.

Answer (score 0):

It's well documented here: [Cloud Functions Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating)
In short you have to provide your service account credentials in the authentication header.

To get your credentials use the [Google Auth Client library](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-auth/1.14.0/reference/google.oauth2.id_token.html#google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token). If you are testing from local you should create a service account JSON and load it to the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` but on App Engine it will work from scratch.

After you have gotten your token, pass it as an auth header like so:

```py
    auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
    auth_token = google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token(auth_req, cloud_function_url)

    response = requests.post(cloud_function_url, json=payload, headers={"Authorization" : f"Bearer {auth_token}"})
```